# EF Core - Self referencing relationship with custom foreign/principal key not mapped properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement a self-referencing relationship in EF Core.
I am trying to use a custom foreign key and principal key that are not mapped to a real database columns.

With the below code, I get the error

> 'No backing field could be found for property 'HeadOfHouseholdForeignKey' of entity type 'Person' and the property does not have a setter

Is there a way to have these foreign/principal keys which aren't mapped to a column in the DB?
Is there a way to do it nicely in EF Core?

Example:

PersonContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        DbSet<Person> People;
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasOne(p => p.HeadOfHouseHold)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.HeadOfHouseholdForeignKey)
                .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.HeadOfHouseholdPrincipalKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string FamilyName { get; set; }

        public string PersonSequenceNumber { get; set; }

        public Person HeadOfHouseHold { get; set; }

        public string HeadOfHouseholdForeignKey
        {
            get
            {
                // Head of household always has '01' as PersonSequenceNumber in DB, other members increment from 01 to 02, 03, etc
                if (PersonSequenceNumber != "01")
                {
                    return FamilyName + "01";
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public string HeadOfHouseholdPrincipalKey
        {
            get
            {
                return FamilyName + PersonSequenceNumber;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Foreign key is a database concept. What do You want to achieve by having "foreign key" only code model?

Comment: I want to be able to use EF Core .Include() method to simplify fetching related data

Comment: And what table do You want to .Include()? Person maybe?

Comment: And what keys of related table look like? Are they something like 'Tom01'?

Comment: Something like `People.Include(p => p.HeadOfHousehold)`. I want to include a record from the same table (hence self referencing), with the composite key { FamilyName, PersonSequenceNumber }. For example, Jones01 would be Dad, Jones02 would be Mom, etc

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have relation in EF Core, which is not defined using database beneath. You are trying to use foreign key by using read-only property and this is not supported.

If You simply want to .Include() `Person` table, You maybe could use composite key:

```
.HasForeignKey(p => new { p.FamilyName, p.PersonSequenceNumber) });
```

See examples at: [EF Core Relations #Foreign key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-composite-key%2Ccomposite-key#foreign-key) and [EF Core Relations #Principal key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-composite-key%2Ccomposite-key#principal-key)

PS. I suppose principal key should be from referenced table, not current:

```
.HasPrincipalKey(parent => parent.HeadOfHouseholdPrincipalKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating your model, you need to map exactly what is in the database.
So if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you need to do 2 things:

1. Remove these declarations for the columns that are not in the database. You need a primary key in the database and that's the only thing you need to declare when creating your model:

   ```
   // Remove these as these fields are not in the DB
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.HeadOfHouseholdForeignKey)
   .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.HeadOfHouseholdPrincipalKey);
   ```
2. Add the [NotMapped](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute to the properties that do not have a column in the database as follows:

   ```
   [NotMapped]
   public string HeadOfHouseholdForeignKey
   // ...

   [NotMapped]
   public string HeadOfHouseholdPrincipalKey
   // ...
   ```